# Multi-Device hybrid App - Build results in www empty folders

Tags: javascript, cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I have an app made in VS2013 using MDHA which when built used to work perfectly fine, now though, the www folder has css, js and img folders within which are all empty. Can anyone offer any advice? I have tried deleting .cordova but to no avail.

Would really appreciate any advice, thank you!

Comment: Are you able to deploy to any emulator or device and do you get build failures in VS?

Comment: I can only build/rebuild as release for android, everything else fails. Closing question as no longer a big issue. environment problem most likely. Thanks.